# probability of 6 events

Tags: probability

this might be a very specific question

i have a coin with to sides ("true" and "false") and i need to flip the coin 6 times

- each "true" flip is represented by a letter from A to F the first flip being A and the sixth being F
- every flip after the first replaces the letters before it if the outcome was "true" (B replaces A, C replaces A and B etc)
- i can set the outcome of a flip from 0% to 100% with 0% being "false" and 100% being "true"
- there must be at least one flip set to 100% in order to at least have one "true" outcome

what percentage do i set the other 5 flips so that every outcome is equally likely to happen?

example:

- flip A: 100%
- flip B: 50%
- flip C: 0%
- flip D: 0%
- flip E: 0%
- flip F: 0%

after the first flip the outcome is A

after the second flip there is a 50% chance that the first outcome is replaced by B

so A and B are equally likely to happen

i would appreciate any help with this and hope that my explanation is as understandable as possible

Comment: From your description, it's not clear what are those % and what is the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I can only guess what you're trying to describe, but I'm confident that solving this problem for *two* flips will put you on the path to solving it for any number of flips.  Hint: think recursively.  Maybe you are looking for [Knuth's "Algorithm P"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/228263/919)?

Answer (score 0):

What is described sounds equivalent to flipping for outcome F first and A last and stopping at the first heads. More generally, for $n$ outcomes, the probability of heads for outcome $n$ should be set to probability $p_n=\frac{1}{n}$. Outcome $n-1$ is selected only if the flip for outcome $n$ results in tails and the flip for outcome $n-1$ results in heads:

$$p_{n-1}(1-p_n)=\frac{1}{n}$$
Solve for $p_{n-1}$:
$$p_{n-1}=\frac{1}{n(1-p_n)}=\frac{1}{n(1-1/n)}=\frac{1}{n-1}$$
Outcome $n-2$ is selected only if the flips for outcomes $n$ and $n-1$ both result in tails and the flip for outcome $n-2$ results in heads:
$$p_{n-2}(1-p_n)(1-p_{n-1})=\frac{1}{n}$$
$$p_{n-2}=\frac{1}{n-2}$$
We can see a pattern emerging. The probability of heads for the $i^{\text{th}}$ outcome should be set to $i^{-1}$.

The probability of getting outcome $n-k$ in the end is
$$p_{n-k}\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(1-p_{n-i})=\frac{1}{n-k}\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}\frac{n-i-1}{n-i}=\frac{1}{n}$$

Checking with a quick simulation in R:

```
n <- 6L
tabulate(max.col(t(matrix(runif(n*1e6L), n, 1e6) < 1/(1:n)), "last"), n)/1e6
#> [1] 0.165888 0.166987 0.166336 0.167132 0.166237 0.167420
```